# Is there a way to protect visitor from directly accessing api url through browser in Laravel Sanctum

Tags: php, laravel, web-applications

Is there a way to protect visitors from directly accessing API URL through the browser in **Laravel Sanctum** without the user having to authenticate. I am building a quiz app and I want to block visitors from directly accessing the API URL through the browser.

In the documentation, it is stated that the user has to authenticate in order to protect API routes with auth middleware but in quiz app I want users to play even without having to authenticate.

Comment: Just don't allow any other requests from that API apart from your quiz app. Whenever your quiz app hits that API, send some other parameter along with that to make sure i't only coming from your quiz app only.

Answer (score 0):

> I am building a quiz app and **I want to block visitors from** directly **accessing the API** URL through the browser.
>
> [ .... ]
>
> but in quiz app **I want users to play** even **without having to authenticate**.

If the gateway to your service is gonna be the API, you've contradicted yourself.

As for the concept itself, surely you can create an API which allows guests as well. I don't think you need Laravel Sanctum afterall, you could start with the [original Laravel distribution](https://github.com/laravel/laravel).

Comment: I just found a solution by adding api keys but the problem is when i use axios the api key is vieweble to anyone who peaks into app.js through browser dev tools.

Comment: You should create a unique API key for each user who accesses your app.